# MySQL - selecting the lowest value from a table using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

The following query selects the lowest price product in every product line from `products` table :

```
SELECT 
    a.productline, a.productCode, a.productName, a.buyprice
FROM
    products a
        LEFT JOIN
    products b ON a.productline = b.productline
        AND b.buyprice < a.buyprice
WHERE
    b.productcode IS NULL;
```

You can find the code [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-min/). An online editor to test the code is [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-min/#5).

I just cannot understand how the query with a given `productLine` from table `a` finds the lowest `buyPrice`. For a certain row in `a` with a certain `productLine` , there may be multiple rows from table `b`. 1) So how is the lowest one selected ? 2) How can `b.productcode` be ever `NULL` as table `a` and `b` are the same table ?

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause and use `SELECT *` - Then you will see how LEFT JOIN works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to run this query at that site:

```
SELECT 
    a.productline, a.productName, a.buyprice, b.buyprice, b.productName
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products b ON a.productline = b.productline
        AND b.buyprice < a.buyprice
ORDER BY 
   a.productline, b.buyprice, a.buyprice, b.productName
LIMIT 5
```

You get this result:

```
| productline  |             productName             | buyprice | buyprice |             productName             |
|--------------|-------------------------------------|----------|----------|-------------------------------------|
| Classic Cars | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |    15.91 | (null)   | (null)                              |
| Classic Cars | 1982 Lamborghini Diablo             |    16.24 | 15.91    | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |
| Classic Cars | 1966 Shelby Cobra 427 S/C           |    29.18 | 15.91    | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |
| Classic Cars | 1970 Plymouth Hemi Cuda             |    31.92 | 15.91    | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |
| Classic Cars | 1961 Chevrolet Impala               |    32.33 | 15.91    | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |
```

So, if you look at the far right column you will see "1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition" repeated many times. This is because

1. the products table is compared to itself (*this is called a "self join"*)
2. the join condition `a.productline = b.productline` means "Classic Cars" are matched against "Classic Cars" (and so on for each productline value) so **ALL** "Classic Cars" from `b` are compared to **EACH** "Classic Car" in `a` (*and you get lots and lots of rows by the way*).
3. then, the **a.buyprice** is compared to **b.buyrice** which MUST be LESS THAN the **a.buyprice**. However the cheapest car ($15.91) cannot have a matching row that is less than that cheapest price, so the `LEFT JOIN` allows that un-matched row to be included in the result and all `b` columns are NULL for that cheapest car row.
4. then the `where clause` removes all rows where `b.productcode` has any value (as these are of no interest in finding the cheapest a.buyprice)

And therefore only the cheapest (lowest) prices are listed when any column from `b` IS NULL

```
| productline  |             productName             | buyprice | buyprice |             productName             |
|--------------|-------------------------------------|----------|----------|-------------------------------------|
| Classic Cars | 1958 Chevy Corvette Limited Edition |    15.91 | (null)   | (null)                              |
```

Comment: `However the cheapest car ($15.91) cannot have a matching row` - if it was mentioned that  this cheapest car  was from table `a` , then it would be easier to understand.

Comment: `AND b.buyprice < a.buyprice WHERE   b.productcode IS NULL;` - why can't it select the highest `buyPrice` instead of the lowest one ?

Comment: It can! just reverse the predicate to require a price higher than the current row. ( use > instead of < )  then the same logic applies except that you discover the highest price not the lowest